# Error trying to customize Reports in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, error

Error received :

> Obsolete Environment. Localization context was changed to: language English, locale English (Malaysia).   Click here to return to the previous page.

I tried googling this error everywhere but I don't see anyone reporting this issue.
This error occurs when I press any of these buttons :

1. Run report
2. Customize
3. printable View
4. Export Details

Background if it helps:

In Sandbox environment, I created this report from **standard** OOTB called "Opportunities with Products and Schedules" and in **Summary Format** form.

Screenshot of the fields I used :
[image: Oppty Schedule Report]

How to resolve it?

Comment: Have you checked out [this one](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_reports_error_obsolete.htm&type=0) and [one more](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hJU2AAM)? Would you also provide more details (what fields you are using in your report), maybe share a screenshot of the report and error?

Comment: Thanks for helping. The error is Obsolete environment not 'obsolete report'. I have updated my question to give u more details